# Conditional formatting highlighting cells it shouldn't

Tags: excel

I'm trying to highlight rows that have mismatched numbers in columns M and H. The formula I entered is triggering only a few, out of hundreds, that match.

Currently my formula applies to: `=$A:$Z` and the formula is `=IF($M2<>$H2,1,0)`.

A few rows are getting highlighted where the figures do match, and therefore should not be highlighting.

I've tried adjusting the 'applies to' to only

```
$M:$M 
$M:$H, and currently 
$A:$Z
```

Formula as

```
=IF($M2<>$H2,1,0)
=$M2<>$H2
```

All combos still highlight the same cells that are matching. I've also tried formatting each column as text, numbers, and general, to no effect.

I'm expecting rows that have figures in M and H that match, no remain unfilled. And I want those rows that have different numbers in M than that of M, to highlight.

Comment: Change the `2`s to `1`.  It should refer to the upper cell.

Comment: Note: you can use a simpler formula: `=$M1<>$H1`. No need for IF.

Comment: Thanks - I just deleted the = in front of [$M2<>$H2], and now it's working... sorry to bother.